# Eclipse not respond when try to configure GIT

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit
SSD Kingston
i5-4690
Eclipse version: ALL
Workspace: empty
Problem: everytime i try to configure TEAM > GIT > configuration or i try to import/create local/remote git, eclipse freeze until i force to close it with task.
I have already tryed a fresh install ( juno/mars/neon/oxygen ) 32/64 bit with and without installer with no good results

```
!SESSION 2017-06-27 00:39:29.113 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170531-2000
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2017-06-27 00:39:50.111
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Enrico'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2017-06-27 00:41:04.510 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170531-2000
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data file:/C:/Users/Enrico/workspace/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2017-06-27 00:41:13.439
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Enrico'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2017-06-27 00:42:32.097 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170531-2000
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2017-06-27 00:42:42.119
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Enrico'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2017-06-27 00:45:05.785 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170531-2000
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data file:/C:/Users/Enrico/workspace/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2017-06-27 00:45:13.542
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Enrico'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2017-06-27 00:47:39.707 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170531-2000
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2017-06-27 00:47:49.374
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Enrico'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

MY SOLUTION:
"Delete all folders from USER_FOLDER ( .p2 .eclipse ) and PROGRAMFILES. Remember to reboot!!!! Now all works fine with eclipse oxygen and git project"

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to get it working? I have exactly the same issue after upgrading to Windows Creators Update on Win Pro 64 bit.

Comment: Delete all folders from USER_FOLDER ( .p2 .eclipse ) and PROGRAMFILES.  Remember to reboot!!!!  Now all works fine with eclipse oxygen and git project

Answer (score 22):

The GIT plugin of Eclipse tries to detect whether to use the GIT executable of the OS, or the build-in GIT. Therefor it uses a `bash` command.

Before the Windows Creators Update, the `bash` command did not exist (unless you've installed CygWin or a similar program). With the Windows Creators Update, a new feature `Windows Subsystem for Linux` is added. When the `bash` command is first called, it asks whether to install this feature or not.

So in order to fix GIT in Eclipse, you just have to manually run `bash` once and install it. You may have to activate Developer Mode in Windows.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. I have been struggling to fix this for days. Just for sake of knowledge, how did you reach this solution?

Comment: It's been a while, but if I remember correctly I figured it out by looking into the source code of eGit, the Eclipse Git plugin.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was desperately searching for a solution.

Comment: This is bad design.  The windows version should use batch command at the very least.  Know where it can be reported?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue: Eclipse was not responding when trying to configure git.

I used Java VisualVM and discovered that Eclipse was not responding because of Eclipse JGit was searching for git.

```
 at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000cf57bf60> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000cf382838> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000cf382838> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.readPipe(FS.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.readPipe(FS.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_Win32.discoverGitExe(FS_Win32.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.discoverGitSystemConfig(FS.java:647)
```

I am on Windows, Git for Windows was installed, but for a strange reason the Environment Variable pointing on Git was not defined.

I had to add the directory of git.exe `(C:\Program Files\Git\bin)` in the System variable named `Path`.

Eclipse is not freezing anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Adding git to the path variable on Windows 10, using Eclipse Oxygen worked for me! TY :D

Comment: Hi Tiffany, welcome to SO. Feel free to expand on your answer on how the user asking can reach positive results from your suggested approach, so your answer looks complete.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse may be searching for a bash executable.

If you have Cygwin installed, add the Cygwin bin directory  (for example, C:\cygwin64\bin) to your Path environment variable. Then restart eclipse.

The Cygwin bin directory includes bash.exe.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have already installed Git or not.
2. See if git variable is properly set in environment or not.
3. Try to execute `git` command in command prompt, it should work first.

Once all above steps are Okay, try restarting eclipse in clean mode.