# Eclipse (Oxygen) Stops Responding When Accessing EGit?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, installation, eclipse-oxygen

I can't seem to access eGit or use any related features in Eclipse Oxygen.

I have tried everything, and even wiped the meta, pool, and eclipse information to a complete re-install but still end up with the same issue.

For your information, I have 2 versions of Eclipse installed, Java and Java EE (if that might be a problem).  I also have GitHub for Windows installed.

Some symptoms (i.e. when Eclipse stops responding):

1. Opening eGit perspective (it is possible if I don't have any projects in explorer, and open it from start after deleting metadata folder).  Then it works until I open git projects.
2. Importing git & eclipse projects.  Auto share git projects does not complete (or takes a long time - I stop it after 5-10 minutes).
3. Importing git project as Git Project (from import screen).
4. Importing git project from eGit perspective.

Edit:  Additional symptoms:

5. Clone external git repository.
6. Load got project without git autoshare, and share project...then no response.
7. Accessing Team->Git->Configuration in Preferences.
8. Attempt to share new project.

Edit:  I have now discovered (after installing previous Eclipse Neon version) that EGit still fails to work.  Which may mean there is something deeper wrong with my setup/system.  I hope I don't have to reinstall Windows on my system with a clean wipe. :(

I have tried just about everything.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "just about everything" means...?

Comment: Everything from reinstalling twice to finding a solution on the internet, with no luck.  I did get it to work with Oxgen last week, but don't know what happened to cause this.

Comment: The UI freezes when cloning a Git repository, right? Even with a new empty workspace?

Comment: Yes, that is number 5.

Comment: What kind of environment is it? What kind of hardware is involved? Where are the clones, on a local disk or on some kind of network share?

Comment: Windows 10, HP Spectre x360, Eclipse versions on D Drive, local disk.  Note I didn't any issues with Neon.

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem? I am facing similar problem and have tried new installation, new workspace, cleaning up git repositories etc. Eclipse hangs whenever I try to open Git Repositories view or even GIT configuration preference view.

Comment: Solution for this problem is probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/44910936/968795. It worked for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDIT: As suggested, here is another fix to a similar (or same?) issue:
>   [Eclipse not respond when try to configure GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769837/eclipse-not-respond-when-try-to-configure-git/44910936#44910936)

As I was working on my project, an exclamation point popped up.  Attempting to resolve this issue, I came across this solution from [here](http://www.kriblog.com/ide/sts/how-to-remove-red-exclamation-mark-on-eclipse-project.html):

1. Right click on your project -> Close Project. it will Close your project and all opened file(s) of the project
2. Right click on your project -> Open Project. it will Open your project and rebuild your project, Hopefully it will fix red exclamation mark

This not only fixed my project, but finally granted me access to eGit features in Eclipse.

Comment: I have no project in my workspace, still I am facing this issue. This answer is not applicable in my case.